# How to create custom tooltip for Google chart with tail arrow?

Tags: google-visualization

I am trying to create the custom tooptip for Google Cline chart using the below code:

```
function(files, date, serverName) {
        var htmlTooltip = '<div class ="custom-tooltip"> <label class = "tooltip-label"> Files: </label><label>' + files + '</label > <br> <label class = "tooltip-label">Date:</label><label>' + date + '</label > <br> <label class="tooltip-label" >Server:</label><label id="path">' + serverName + '</label> </div>';
        return htmlTooltip;
}
```

I am not able to create the tooltip tail arrow with the direction as google chart is displaying the tooltip arrow towards the selected point.

Please give me any idea on how to implement this.

Comment: The HTML tooltips do not include a tail arrow, and there is no built-in support for adding one.  In theory, you could construct your HTML tooltip to include a tail arrow, but making the tail arrow point toward the data point would be difficult to accomplish.